# Can not edit .vimrc file

Tags: vim, readonly, plugin

I have just installed spf13 plugin for vim and I want to customize .vimrc file.

When ever I try to save the edits it says: ".vimrc" E166: Can't open linked file for writing
syntastic: info: no active checkers for filetype vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue

I have tried saving with w! and everything that says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606646/how-to-change-file-permission-from-within-vi)

How can I edit .vimrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spf13 documentation says you must do your local changes in a [~/.vimrc.local](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim#customization) file.  If you really want to mess with the `~/.vimrc` file I suggest you use either another editor or try to force the filetype using `:set filetype=txt` before saving.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a misconfiguration of the Syntastic plugin (as it reads): https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic

Perhaps you could try to deassociate Syntastic in your .vimrc from checking .vim filetypes - the readme seems to have tips on that!